# A satellite moves in parabolic or straight line path when it escapes and when its total mechanical energy is zero.How can ang. momentum cons. be used?

Tags: gravity

When a satellite escapes from the orbit of a planet it can have Mechanical energy equal to or greater than 0 but when it is equal to zero it can have a parabolic or straight-line path. When velocity is just opposite to centripetal force (here gravitational) then straight line and if at any angle then parabolic. Now here angular momentum conservation principle is applicable. But how?   [image]

Comment: Do you mean how can it be conserved for a parabolic path or the straight line path, or do you mean how can it be used to find the real path after leaving the planet?

Comment: Can you prove how is the path straight -line or parabolic when E=0 (hint: angular momentum conservation and energy conservation are applicable and consider planet and satellite as point mass)